# JFace SourceViewer - AnnotationPainter for widgets

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I want to add some **SWT** controls into `SourceViewer`.

Currently i am using `AnnotainerPainter`. It looks fine, except one thing and that is **i don't know how to dispose the controls when the annotation is removed**, because the `AnnotationerPainter` doesn't provide any info to 
`ITextStyleStrategy` instance about what annotation it is processing (in that case i could just add the SWT control to it and later remove it when the annotation is going to be removed from `AnnotationModel`).

```java
painter.addTextStyleStrategy("CONTROL", new AnnotationPainter.ITextStyleStrategy() {

            private SourceViewer fViewer = ClassSourceViewer.this;

            @Override
            public void applyTextStyle(StyleRange styleRange, Color annotationColor) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(styleRange.start);
                System.out.println(styleRange.length);
                final Button button = new Button(fViewer.getTextWidget(), SWT.PUSH);
                button.setFont(new Font(Display.getCurrent(), "Tahoma", 7, SWT.NORMAL));
                button.setText("jmp to 24");
                button.setBackground(fViewer.getTextWidget().getBackground());
                button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                        button.dispose();
                        ((AnnotationModel) fViewer.getAnnotationModel()).removeAllAnnotations();
                    }
                });
                button.pack();
                button.setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
                Rectangle rect = button.getBounds();
                int ascent = 2*rect.height/3;
                int descent = rect.height - ascent;
                button.setLocation(fViewer.getTextWidget().getLocationAtOffset(styleRange.start));
                styleRange.metrics = new GlyphMetrics(ascent, descent,rect.width);
                //styleRange.foreground = new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0);
                //styleRange.
                //styleRange.background = new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 255, 255, 0);


            }
        });
```

Comment: `ITextStyleStrategy` is really only intended to apply text styles and not to create additional controls.

Comment: greg-449: but i need to set metrics for at least one characater so my control has enough space.